# removing a % sign and parsing result as an integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, percentage

I am scraping an XML file and returning a load of percentages, pulled out directly as a percentage sometimes negative with the % sign already attached e.g.

```
-38%
-2%
4%
25%
```

I am trying to do a filter such as this:

```
if percentage < 20.0 : continue;
```

However I cannot perform this filter, I assume as a result of the % symbol.

For reference I use:

```
cell['roi']
```

To get the percentages, iterating through each row using:

```
for row in xmlload1['rows']:
    cell = row["cell"]
```

How do I get around this % symbol? Is there an easy way?

Comment: Please show the actual code that you tried and the exception that you got (with traceback), instead of just saying that you can't get the code to work.

Comment: Also, as a side note: You don't need semicolons at the end of lines in Python, and shouldn't use them. At best, it's visual noise; at worst, it confuses people into trying to guess what you were trying to do that required the unusual semicolon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't perform that filter because you're trying to compare a string (like `"4%"`) to a float (`20.0`). In Python 3, this will raise a `TypeError`; in Python 2, it will "work", but all strings will be treated as greater than the number `20.0`, so it won't do any good.

You need to convert the string to a float before you can use it as a float. But you don't want to convert the *whole* string, just the part before the `"%"` character. (Because `4%` isn't a number, it's only the `4` that's a number.)

So, let's do it in two steps: use [`rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove the `"%"`, then use [`float`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) to convert it to a float.

```
cell = float(row["cell"].rstrip("%"))
```

Comment: Both answers the same, but I gave you the accepted answer because I really appreciate it when people take the time to explaning the logic, I am new to coding, and this was really useful.

Comment: For my actuall code, which contains more than just these percentages, It wasnt appropriate to use `cell = float(row["cell"].rstrip("%"))` instead I used the following, `roi = cell['roi']
        roi_without_percentage_symbol = int(roi.strip("%\n "))
        if roi_without_percentage_symbol < 20.0 : continue;`

Comment: @AEA: That makes sense. Although for cases like this, I often do it in two steps: `roi.strip().rstrip("%")`. In English: remove all extraneous whitespace from both sides, so I know I've got exactly `"4%"`, then remove the `"%"`. Also, if you're converting to `int` instead of `float`, you really should check `< 20` instead of `< 20.0`, because `20 < 20.0` isn't guaranteed to be false.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a string to `strip` which will strip the characters passed in the passed string, the below will strip %, newlines and spaces:

```
cell = int(row["cell"].strip("%\n "))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the prompt reply, just for expanding my python knowledge what does the \n function do. Kind regards AEA

Comment: `\n` is not a function. it is the representation of a new line character.